# Spring tool Suite Remote Debug over ssh port forward too slow

Tags: java, docker, eclipse, remote-debugging, spring-tool-suite

There is a java app deployed on remote machine , I use port forward to debug it .
But the connection takes too much time .

On running ssh connection in debug mode I get below logs

```
debug1: Connection to port 5005 forwarding to 10.1.1.234 port 8000 requested.
debug1: channel 2: new [direct-tcpip]
```

In eclipse I get no error or logs when ran eclipse in debug mode with console log.

Is there a way to speed up the connection time and speed of debugging .
I have set all java debug properties in STS as optimal as possible to speed up debug but thats not helping .

I have disabled all monitors and show threads in debug
Here is configuration
[image: here is configuration]
More details and logs and data on issue here
https://github.com/eclipse-jdt/eclipse.jdt.debug/issues/39

Comment: More details here https://github.com/eclipse-jdt/eclipse.jdt.debug/issues/39